# Creating strongly typed view

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I am trying to create a search page, which searches the details of the user based on the Username. My problem is I am not able to create a strongly typed text box for the search box. I created a Model view and in spite of that I am unable to fix my issue. My View is not able to even compile properly, I am guessing I am going wrong with the Model which binds the view to make it strongly typed. I wish to have 2 text boxes for username and phone number, if the user enters anything inside either of the text box it should return the matching user profile.

This is the View Model:

```
public class UserSearchViewModel
{
    public string userName { get; set; }
    public string phoneNum { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<User> user { get; set; }
}
```

Action method:

```
public ActionResult Search(UserSearchViewModel mod)
{
    IEnumerable<User> u1 = null;
    u1 = db.Users.Where(p => p.UserName.Contains(mod.userName) ||   p.PhoneNum.Contains(mod.phoneNum));
    return View(u1);
}
```

View:

```
@model HindiMovie.Models.UserSearchViewModel
@using( Html.BeginForm("Search", "User", FormMethod.Get))
{
    @Html.TextBox("UserName")
}
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.UserName)</th>
    <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.FirstName)</th>
    <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.LastName)</th>
    <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.PhoneNum)</th>
    <th></th>
  </tr>

  @foreach (var item in Model.user) {
  <tr>
    <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.FirstName)</td>
    <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.LastName)</td>
    <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.UserName)</td>
  </tr>
  }
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

A way to go would be to create a wrapper class

```
public class UserSearchViewModel
{
     public string UserName {get;set;}
     public string PhoneNumber {get;set;}
     public IEnumerable<User> Users {get;set;}
}
```

The model would be UserSearchViewModel instead of IEnumerable and your foreach would loop through Model.Users instead Model.

[This](https://lostechies.com/jimmybogard/2009/06/30/how-we-do-mvc-view-models/) and [this](http://cpratt.co/entities-are-not-models/) are a couple of articles detailing the use of ViewModels (an arbitrary class that exists solely to provide data for a view) vs. using your Enity/Database models directly in the view.

Comment: Sorry I did not understand what you explained.

Comment: Rather than using your collection of users as your model, you would make another class that had your collection of users and whatever other properties you needed.

Comment: That works now, but the table header is not working. I tried  @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.FirstName), but this doesn't seem to work. The error I get when it tries to go to the view is:    The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbQuery`1[HindiMovie.Models.User]', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'HindiMovie.Models.UserSearchViewModel'.

Comment: You have to return the type your view needs.  So instead of returning u1 return a UserSearchViewModel.  mod = mod ?? new UserSearchViewModel; mod.user = u1; return View (mod);  For the display name you could do something like @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.user[0].UserName, but if your user collection doesn't have any records it'll throw a null reference excpetion.

Comment: Is there any better way to add the Table headers? Because I want the them to be dynamic and not hard code the column names.

Comment: you could try the WebGrid helper.  new WebGrid(model.Users).GetHtml()

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/89815/discussion-between-sid-and-miniver-cheevy).

Answer (score 0):

Inside the form element, use

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.userName )
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.phoneNum)
```

But the reason you view wont compile is because you model does not contain a properties `UserName`, `FirstName` etc so you cannot use `@Html.DisplayNameFor(m => m.UserName)` in your table headings.

Either hard code them

```
<th>User name</th>
```

or use

```
<th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(m => m.user.FirstOrDefault().UserName)</th>
```

Note that the collection does not need to contain any items for this to work.

Comment: It does not work with the <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(m => m.user[0].UserName)</th>. I get an error stating: Cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<HindiMovie.Models.User>'.

Comment: See edit for usage if the collection is `IEnumerable<T>`